# How to redirect to an html page with parameters?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages running on a localhost server and would like for the first page to redirect to the other one but with parameters so that I can use queries on the second page. This is my code in javascript:

```
var number = 5;
window.location.href = "page2.html/?numberID=number";
```

So that the new page will have the URL: `localhost/page2.html/?numerID=5`, but code just gives me a 404 page not found error, how do I fix this?

Comment: try storing the parameters in local storage. redirect and then grab the parameters from local storage

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the slash between the page name and the question mark, otherwise the web server will think you are requesting a folder named /page2.html/, hence you are getting 404 - not found

```
localhost/page2.html?numberID=5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = 5;
window.location.href = "page2.html?number="+number;
```